# bash script unexpected end of file pterodactyl

Tags: bash, docker

I am trying to run a custom egg through the Pterodactyl panel however, I get the error "/entrypoint.sh: line 30: syntax error: unexpected end of file"

My Docker image is as followed;

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
MAINTAINER Amelia, <me@amelia.fun>
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y dos2unix curl gnupg2 git-core zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libffi-dev yarn build-essential gpg-agent zip unzip software-properties-common git default-jre python3-pip python-minimal python-pip ffmpeg libopus-dev libsodium-dev libpython2.7 libpython2.7-dev wget php7.2 php7.2-common php7.2-cli php7.2-fpm
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x -o nodesource_setup.sh
RUN bash nodesource_setup.sh
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN rm -rf nodesource_setup.sh
RUN adduser -D -h /home/container container
USER container
ENV  USER=container HOME=/home/container
WORKDIR /home/container
COPY ./entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
CMD ["/bin/bash", "/entrypoint.sh"]
```

and my entrypoint.sh is as followed;

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/container
MODIFIED_STARTUP=`eval echo $(echo ${STARTUP_PARAMETERS} | sed -e 's/{{/${/g' -e 's/}}/}/g')`
rm -rf *
git clone ${REPO_PARAMETERS}
cd */
if grep -q 'Java' AppType
then
    ${STARTUP_PARAMETERS}
if grep -q 'PHP' AppType
then
    ${STARTUP_PARAMETERS}
elif grep -q 'Python2' AppType
then
    [ -f "requirements.txt" ] && pip2 install -r requirements.txt ${STARTUP_PARAMETERS} || ${STARTUP_PARAMETERS}
elif grep -q 'Python3' AppType
then
    [ -f "requirements.txt" ] && pip3 install -r requirements.txt ${STARTUP_PARAMETERS} || ${STARTUP_PARAMETERS}
elif grep -q 'NodeJS' AppType
then
    npm install
    ${STARTUP_PARAMETERS}
else
    echo "Application not supported"
fi
echo "${MODIFIED_STARTUP}"
```

the Bash file is nowhere near 30 lines long so I'm not really sure.

The guide I used can also be found [here](https://pterodactyl.io/community/config/eggs/creating_a_custom_image.html#creating-the-dockerfile)

Comment: There is at least one `fi` missing. Have a look at https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Or actually, the `if` that checks if the `AppType` is PHP should actually be a `elif`

Answer (score 2):

The immediate problem is that you have two `if` statements, but only one of them is closed with `fi`; it looks to me like the second one should be `elif`. But there are a number of other things that look like bad ideas to me:

- `cd` commands in scripts should (almost) always have error tests -- for example, if `cd /home/container` fails for some reason, the rest of the script (including `rm -rf *`) will run in an unexpected location. Now, a self-destroying Docker environment may not be as big a deal as a self-destroying real system, but it's still not a good thing. I'd use something like this instead:

  ```
  cd /home/container || {
      echo "Error -- can't move to /home/container, something rotten in Denmark." >&2
      exit 1
  }
  ```

  A similar comment applies to `cd */`.
- The next line, that sets `MODIFIED_STARTUP`, is a mishmash of bad ideas. I'm not familiar with what's going to be in `$STARTUP_PARAMETERS`, but in general: Use `$( )` instead of backticks (and not a weird mix of both). `echo $(somecommand)` is pretty much a no-op, just run the command directly. Also, variable references (and similar expansions like `$( )`) should almost always be in double-quotes (exception: on the right side of an assignment). And `eval` is generally dangerous, and should be avoided if possible. I you give me an example of what `$STARTUP_PARAMETERS` looks like, I could probably give a cleaned-up version of this.
- The big `if ... elif...` etc has several conditions that do the same thing, e.g.

  ```
  elif grep -q 'Python2' AppType
  then
      [ -f "requirements.txt" ] && pip2 install -r requirements.txt ${STARTUP_PARAMETERS} || ${STARTUP_PARAMETERS}
  elif grep -q 'Python3' AppType
  then
      [ -f "requirements.txt" ] && pip3 install -r requirements.txt ${STARTUP_PARAMETERS} || ${STARTUP_PARAMETERS}
  ```

  On the DRY principle (Don't Repeat Yourself), it'd be better to have a single test for all equivalent situations, like this:

  ```
  elif grep -q 'Python2' AppType || grep -q 'Python3' AppType
  then
      [ -f "requirements.txt" ] && pip2 install -r requirements.txt ${STARTUP_PARAMETERS} || ${STARTUP_PARAMETERS}
  ```

  or even:

  ```
  elif grep -q 'Python[23]' AppType
  then
      [ -f "requirements.txt" ] && pip2 install -r requirements.txt ${STARTUP_PARAMETERS} || ${STARTUP_PARAMETERS}
  ```

  BTW, the use of `${STARTUP_PARAMETERS}` without quotes is setting off warning bells for me here, but may be inevitable -- again, I don't know its format. And the `&& ... ||` construction isn't always a safe replacement for `if then else fi`, since it can run both branches. In this script, if requirements.txt exists but the `pip2 install` command fails, it'll go ahead and run `${STARTUP_PARAMETERS}` as well. Is that intentional? If not, I'd use a proper `if` statement instead.